# Retrieving Data from the BattleNet

Tags: data-retrieval

I have seen sites like "sc2ranks.com" and I totally wonder how they get information I could only access when being ingame.
I mean how can I access for example the StarCraft II EU Ladder?
Is this just an URL we have to access / download or does this require hooking the client in some way with injections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every region has an armory associated with it, which you can find on http://battle.net. Global rankings like on sc2ranks and other sites cannot be found on battle.net as they only show division rankings.

If you want to pull information, it has to be done purely with HTML scraping.

Comment: The Battle Net shows CharCode and CharName but the profiles are not accessible by a combination of these, the have some sort of encryption in the profile links.

Comment: It's not an encryption, they just use an internal battle.net id to identify character URLs.